# Response value from Array loop in React

Tags: reactjs, httpresponse

I want to display the color of according to the value from Response.
[data from response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwRzM.png)

If the priority is high, the card color will be red, and if the priority is low the card color  will be green

```
<a style={{ background: 'red' }}>{el.priority}</a>
```

*How I will achieve this:*

```
{el.priority.high}
{el.priority.low}
{el.priority.mild}
{el.priority.blocker}
```

Comment: you can use a simple if and define a new variable for background. or use short if directly. What exactly is your problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aman's answer is correct. In case `background` property doesn't work. You can do it more specifically using `backgroundColor`

```
<a style={{ backgroundColor: el.priority === "high" ? "red" : "green" }}>{el.priority}</a>
```

And if you have priority more than 2 values you can map color on each type and the use index operator to get color from object i.e

```
const bgColors = { 
            high: 'red', 
            low: 'green', 
            medium: 'yellow', 
            none: 'black', 
            default: 'blue'
};

<a style={{ backgroundColor: bgColors[el.priority] }}>{el.priority}</a>
```

It is recommended to use Link from `react-native` or `@react-navigation/native` instead of plan anchor tag. pure anchor tag should be only use for absolute paths.

Comment: basically, data have more values (high, slow, mild, blocker), this condition doesn't work for me. Appreciate your time.

Comment: You didn't mention earlier for multiple values, I've edited the answer according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditional rendering

```
 <a style={{ background: el.priority === "high" ? "red" : "green" }}>{el.priority}</a>
```